# ARKit camera initial position?

Tags: swift, ios11, arkit

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Set the view's delegate
    sceneView.delegate = self

    // Show statistics such as fps and timing information
    sceneView.showsStatistics = true

    // Create a new scene
    let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/exemple.dae")!


    // Set the scene to the view
    sceneView.scene = scene

}
```

I have this model that I imported but I can not place the camera as I want, how can I connect the camera to the camera of my 3D model? or how can I manage the initial camera of the AR?

Comment: Do you mean the initial position and orientation of the model when scene is loaded?

Comment: yes I've tried everything SCNCamera (), sceneView.pointOfView I can not understand how it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the default orientation of your model, first select your model file from Xcode navigator then set camera **Point of view** to ***Front*** (from the bottom bar). This will show the exact view of your model when it is loaded in your scene.

Then, to change the position and orientation of the model, select the ***Node inspector*** from the right side menu (the cube icon) and change the **Euler** x, y, z values.

Comment: I tried to change position and orientation of the model but still does not make me see how I want to camera

Comment: To see how it's shown from camera, you should set camera mode to **Front**. Did you do it?

Comment: I put it but it does not show me anything, can you give me the default parameters of position, euler, scale, to be able to see it?

Comment: for me it's: 

position: 0, 0, 0 -

euler: 0, 0, 0 -

scale: 1, 1, 1

Comment: I put them then these parameters but when I put Front, I do not see anything

Comment: zoom out, do you see your model at all? maybe that's the problem

Comment: I did run your project, it works pretty fine for me! I just changed this line to read the **.scn** file: `let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/Quidditch.scn")!` and changed positions and it worked. Maybe I'm not understanding the question well.

Comment: oh yes sorry I try in multiple example, I miss to recharge the code, but how changed positions? I need to see as soon as I open the app the three rings

Comment: I made these changes to show the rings: 


position: 0,0,0 - euler: 0, 80, 0 - scale: 0.08, 0.08, 0.08 . Let me know if it works for you :)

Comment: position: 0,0,0 - euler: 0, -80, 0 - scale: 1, 1, 1. WORK !! great!

Comment: Glad I could help!